# jQuery Mobile Footer above keyboard

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, footer

Using jQuery Mobile 1.3.2

I have a footer toolbar that is setup like this:

```
<div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed'>......</div>
```

The content contains a textarea. When the user clicks in the textarea, the soft keyboard appears. I need the footer to ALWAYS remain above the soft keyboard (and on top of the textarea). Right now if the user taps again, the footer will disappear, then tap again and the footer re-appears.

I have already tried this:

```
<div data-role='footer' data-position='fixed' data-tap-toggle='false'>....</div>
```

But the problem is that the footer always stays at the bottom and never appears above the keyboard.

Can anyone help me so that when the soft keyboard is shown the footer is always above it - and when the soft keyboard disappears, the footer moves back towards the bottom?+

Comment: Try `<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">......</div>`

Comment: Thats the first thing I have listed.

Comment: what platform are you testing on? It could be the platform isn't fully supported by jquery mobile, have you checked http://jquerymobile.com/gbs/ ? Also what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: See above (jQuery 1.3.2) and I'm testing on Android 4.0.2

Comment: I dont mean Jquery Mobile, I mean straight Jquery, http://jquery.com/ . If your version of Jquery is out dated, then your Jquery Mobile may not function correctly. For JQM 1.3.2, its suggested that you use JQ 1.9.1. Past this in you head and see if the problem presists. 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I am using JQ 1.9.1 and now JQM 1.3.1 and still nothing. data-position='fixed' is not working

Comment: Have you tried to reproduce this on another device or in a simulator? It could just be an issue of actual device and not Jquery/Jquery Mobile. Try to using either the IOS simulator or Android Emulator if its available to you or even post a jsFiddle and I could take a look

Comment: @Sanya. I am also facing the same problem, I am using Jquery Mobile 1.4.0. Have you got any solutions about this problem. if yes, then please guide me how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and it disappeared when using the app in not fullscreen mode...

Check if it solves the problem.

To do that, you have to edit the Android main activity page created by phonegap and adding this:

getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

after:
 super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());